# titlesec package: using the <wrap> shape, can I separate the label and the title by a vertical bar, even if the title spans multiple lines?

Tags: spacing, formatting, titlesec

I am trying to create a section that would ideally look something like the following:
[image: label to the left, vrule, title to the right]

Where the label and title are entirely separated by a vertical bar.

My very naive attempt is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{book}

\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\section}[wrap]
{\Huge\bfseries}
{\thesection \ \vrule }
{0.4em}
{}
\titlespacing{\section}{20pc}{1.5ex plus .1ex minus .2ex}{1pc}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction to Prime Numbers} \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output,

[image: title remains justified in alignment with the label]

The main problem is that the second line of the title is justified in alignment with the label. My intuition is that if put the label inside of a makebox, whose height scales with size of the title, if should fix the justification problem. I am not sure how to go about this though.

Is there any way I can ensure that the title stays left justified, with respect to itself, and have the vertical bar, which separates label and title, also scale with how many lines the title spans?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Could you extend your code fragment into a small example we can compile please? It should begin with your `\documentclass`, end with `\end{document}` and you can use `\usepackage{lipsum}`, `\lipsum[1]` for dummy text, it helps people help you quicker

Comment: @JamesT Thank you for the tip. I've updated the code segment to be compilable with sample text from lipsum.